# React redux application folder structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I understand the concept of a react/redux app.

My question is, is there a preferred way to layout the folder structure  and files.

After doing much research of repos online it appears that everyone does it slightly differently depending on their code flavor.

Angular on the other hand appears that there is a set structure.

Is this what makes react more powerful as you can tweak and adjust as your needs change?

Has the community agreed on any set patterns?

Comment: "everyone does it slightly differently"  I think that's your answer right there. :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As you said yourself; 'Everyone does it slightly differently'. It can help to give some resources right?

I don't know how much experience you currently have with React. I personally started with a traditional structure that made use of the [dumb / smart component pattern](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0), in which I created a `src/redux` folder. Within that I had an actions + reducers folder. This works fine for smaller applications.

I changed that approach after learning about the [Redux Ducks pattern](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux), which removes a lot of boilerplate and copy-pasting reducers.

I'm currently using [this structure](https://github.com/Alserda/react-redux-typescript-boilerplate/tree/master/src).

My suggestion is to try different approaches and see what works best. It depends on how you and your colleagues work in general. For example - if you know that everyone uses their CMD+P to search for specific files, you'd prefer being more explicit in file names, instead of having an `actions/posts.js` and `reducers/posts.js` file you'd prefer creating postsActions.js and postsReducers.js instead. I'd suggest reading these two Medium posts aswell, as inspiration:

- [My journey toward a maintainable project structure for React/Redux](https://hackernoon.com/my-journey-toward-a-maintainable-project-structure-for-react-redux-b05dfd999b5)
- [How to better organize your React applications?](https://medium.com/@alexmngn/how-to-better-organize-your-react-applications-2fd3ea1920f1)

*Edit on 31 july 18:*
Seeing as a lot of people still read this comment and upvote it. I would like to recommend that if you're starting to work on a medium to large project, I would definitely try and get some knowledge about TypeScript and React. I've completely migrated to TypeScript as it makes it a lot easier to step back into a project after a while due to typings, interfaces, generics, and it being more strict. It greatly helps for your overview of the project. Several downsides of it is that you have to learn the typings of the React library and how to use this. [TypeSearch](http://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/) greatly helps to see if there are typings available for a specific library. Also some patterns like higher order components can be awkward in TypeScript due to typings at first.

Comment: I've downvoted this question, thinking that as it says `everyone does it slightly differently`. But your answer change my mind. Thanks :)

Comment: Ducks pattern is great. It let's the directory structure roughly reflect how the state object is nested. And often you work on reducer and actions responsible for the same part of the state, so it makes sense to group them by topic, rather than what type of module they are. Never understood the benefit of having all reducers in one folder for example. Sure it's some kind of structure, but not really helpful at all.

Comment: I've been working with React for a few years now and what I always struggled with, was the application-structure for middle to large applications. I found a way of working now that is really satisfying. I moved to using TypeScript so have a better insight in the data that I'm using. I'm making more use of selectors into my redux-store, so I don't have to do this in my components (and it's reusable) - i use 'reselect' for this. And the other thing that helped me a lot is making more use of 'redux-saga' - this is especially useful for async-background tasks.

Comment: @Alserda Thanks so much for the great positive answer. I really appreciate your help. Many thanks